# how to click in selenium and downloadfile

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:/Users/u/Desktop/python/pythonfile/chromedriver.exe')
    
    driver.get('https://www.plfil.com/actordetail/163964632064582')
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.actorProfileSectionDiv > div.floatDivBorder > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > a').click()
    #driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1]/a/div/div').click()
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.actorProfileSectionDiv > div.floatDivBorder > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > a').click()
    #driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#root > div > div.actorProfileSectionDiv > div.floatDivBorder > div > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2)').click()
    #driver.find_element_by_class_name('div.PlfilButton'[0]).click()
```

I want to click pdf download button but I can't. how can I do that?**

Comment: What are the manual steps required to access the desired element? What error do you see? Update the question with relevant element HTML and error stacktrace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the XPATH of that download button. To do that right click on top of that element and click inspect, right click inspect again and it'll point to which line to look at in the html code. After this right click the line in question and click copy xpath. After that, implement this in:

```
import time

time.sleep(1) # just to make sure the page loads
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "insert xpath here").click()
```

Please note that `find_element_by_xxxxxx` is deprecated and should be using `find_element(By.xxxx, '')` instead.